# For disk space (not speed) of saving Pandas objects, is HDF or Pickle better?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

In Python 3, for disk space (not speed) of saving Pandas objects, is HDF5 or Pickle better? Preferably, also, how much better?

Prior research:

- I searched for an article comparing storage methods, and [here](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/03/16/Fast-Serialization/) is the most popular one. Unfortunately, it only talks about speed, which is less important to me.
- I tested an example object myself, and found that HDF5 and Pickle produced basically the same file size for my example object. But I don't want to just trust my own result, because maybe my result is due to the specific structure/type of data I happened to test with.

Comment: I've never heard of HDF, but an empty dictionary will produce something like `.d(3` in a serialized pickle object.

Comment: Use GZIP compression, it has the highest "compressed by" ratios.  https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/faq/compression.html